# onClickListener on imageview to start new intent

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, imageview

So Im trying to use an onClickListener to pass an image from one activity to a new activity but I cannot figure out how to do it. How it works is the app starts with a listview where you can select an item and it opens a new activity that displays some information and an image below. I want to be able to click the image to open it in a new activity.

Heres my routeDetails.java this is where the image I want to click is located

```
package com.example.zach.listview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.zach.listview.R.id.image;


public class RouteDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

TouchImageView routeImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_details);

    //back button for route details view
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //TextView for route details
    final TextView routeDetailsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.routeDetailsView);
    routeDetailsView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("route"));

    //ImageView for route details
    routeImage = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.routeImage);
    routeImage.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("imageResourceId",   0));


////////// Trying to pass image to new activity

    routeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int imageId = (int) image.getResourceId(i, -1);

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),     FullScreenImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("imageResourceId", imageId);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

 ////////////

}

//back button for route details view
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
    finish();
    return true;
}

}
```

and heres the activity_route_details.xml that goes with it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_route_details"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.zach.listview.RouteDetails">



<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/routeDetailsView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<com.example.zach.listview.TouchImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/routeImage"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/routeDetailsView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

heres my FullScreenImage.java that I want the image to open in

```
package com.example.zach.listview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
* Created by Zach on 11/15/2016.
*/

public class FullScreenImage extends AppCompatActivity {

TouchImageView routeImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_screen_image);

    routeImage = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullScreenImageView);
    routeImage.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("imageFullScreen",     0));
}



}
```

And heres the full_scren_image.xml to go with it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.example.zach.listview.TouchImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@+id/routeImage"
    android:id="@+id/fullScreenImageView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting in the extra with the key `imageResourceId` but you're trying to pull it out with the key `imageFullScreen`. Try using the same key in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Use your image as ByteArray. This worked for me without any problem. In your click listener of the sender activity do the following,

```
Intent senderint = new Intent(context, receiveractivity.class);
Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(view.getBackground());
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
senderint.putExtra("myimage", b);
startActivity(senderint);
```

And in your receiver activity do the following.

```
private void getImage(){
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = null;
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receiverlayout, null);

ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourmainlayout);
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] ba = bundle.getByteArray("myimage");
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba, 0, ba.length());
Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(getResources, bm);
vg.setBackground(dr);
vg.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

call getImage() in your oncreate method of your receiver activity. The context is your application context. Good luck:)

Comment: thanks is there a simpler way to pass the image than that? such as using putextra how the image is passed from my main activity to the route details. Can I do the same thing to pass the image from route details to fullscreenimage?

Comment: I can't think of a simpler way. I am passing the image as byte[] extras here. But when instead of inflating a new Layout you can simply get the extras and convert it to bitmap and use it as a background or  whatever you need to do to fit your needs. Yes you can use it to the reverse as well by put extras and get extras by switching the sender and receiver activities. I hope I made myself clear.