# I want to pass the image in my current activity to a new activity via intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, imageview

Exactly like the title says I'm trying to pass an image from the current activity RouteDetails.java to a new activity FullScreenImage.java via an intent. Can I do this with putExtra getExtra? Could someone give me the code to make this happen? I've been struggling with this all day and I would greatly appreciate it.

heres my RouteDetails.java

```
package com.example.zach.listview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RouteDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

TouchImageView routeImage;
TouchImageView routeImageFull;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_details);

    //back button for route details view
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //TextView for route details
    final TextView routeDetailsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.routeDetailsView);
    routeDetailsView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("route"));

    //ImageView for route details
    routeImage = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.routeImage);
    routeImage.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("imageResourceId",     0));



////////// Trying to pass image to new activity

   routeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {


            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FullScreenImage.class);

            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

////////////

}

//back button for route details view
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
    finish();
    return true;
}

}
```

and my activity_route_details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_route_details"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.zach.listview.RouteDetails">



<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/routeDetailsView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<com.example.zach.listview.TouchImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/routeImage"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/routeDetailsView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and heres the FullScreenImage.java I want to pass the image to

```
package com.example.zach.listview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class FullScreenImage extends AppCompatActivity {

TouchImageView routeImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_screen_image);

    //back button for route details view
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    routeImage = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullScreenImageView);


}

//back button for route details view
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
    finish();
    return true;
}



}
```

and the full_screen_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.example.zach.listview.TouchImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@+id/routeImage"
    android:id="@+id/fullScreenImageView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You already have `getIntent().getIntExtra("imageResourceId")`... So, what issues are you having passing the extras again?

Comment: where is image? in drawable folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClickListener on imageview to start new intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619024/onclicklistener-on-imageview-to-start-new-intent)

Comment: Please do not repost. Edit that post or comment on the answers. The code in that question is even closer to your goal than what you have here

Comment: Your right I shouldn't have reposted I apologize. I was just getting frustrated. As for your first question. I passed the image from my main activity to my route details activity with putextra getextra. But I cannot get it from routedetails to fullscreenimage even though it should be the same thing. The images are stored in an integer array.

Answer (score 0):

**Sender Activity**

```
routeImage.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap image= routeImage.getDrawingCache();

Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Receiver Activity**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagebitmap");
routeImage.setImageBitmap(bmp );
```

Comment: hey thanks I tried this but its not working. The new activity starts but the image is not displayed. Theres no errors though